# Arbitrary objects as argument for lattice functions

Tags: r, lattice

I do not understand how to handle objects, stored in a data.frame, in certain lattice plots. In the second plot I get the error msg bellow. Is it possible to get it to work?

```
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
data<-data.frame(a=I(list(1,2,3)),b=factor(1:3))
ecdfplot(~a|b,data=data
             ,layout=c(1,3)              
             ,panel=function(x,...){
                print(x[[1]])
                panel.xyplot(x[[1]],.5,col=2)
              }
         )
 data<-data.frame(a=I(list(diag(1,2,2),diag(1,2,2),diag(1,2,2))),b=factor(1:3))
 ecdfplot(~a|b,data=data
         ,layout=c(1,3)              
         ,panel=function(x,...){
            print(x[[1]][1,1])
            panel.xyplot(x[[1]][1,1],.5,col=2)
          }
     )


Error in prepanel.default.function(darg = list(give.Rkern = FALSE, n = 50,  : 
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?ecdfplot`:

> For the "formula" method, x is a formula describing the form of conditioning plot, and has to be of the form ~x, where x is assumed to be a numeric vector.

If `x` (in your case the variable `a`) is not numeric, it gets coerced via `as.numeric` at many points along the road to getting plotted. One of those points is in the `prepanel` function.

In your first `data` object, `data$a` can be coerced without an error to a numeric (double) vector. In your second `data` object, `data$a` cannot be successfully coerced.

```
> as.numeric(data$a)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Even though you specify a `panel` function that should work, the `prepanel` function will throw an error.

---

**UPDATE** after clarification:

There is a way to pass arbitrary objects to the panel function, and this is done by passing an argument via the ellipses of `ecdfplot`. The argument must be named in a way that it does not match any named argument in the normal lattice function (and it's best to avoid any named argument in the panel functions used). Furthermore, the formula argument to `x` in `ecdfplot` must also represent data that the `ecdfplot` function can handle, i.e., not a list, as explained above.

In the example below, I pass the data.frame `data4` twice to the plot function: once as the argument `data` and once via the ellipses as the argument `plotData`. This will pass the whole data.frame to the panel function, and it is thus necessary to pass the `subscripts` to the panel function as well, so that the appropriate data can be subscripted.

```
# New example data
data4 <- data.frame(a = 0:2, b = factor(1:3),
  forPrint = letters[1:3],
  forXyplot = I(list(list(x = seq(0, 1, .25), y = rev(seq(0, 1, .25))),
  list(x = seq(0, 1, .5), y = rev(seq(0, 1, .5))), list(x = seq(0, 1, .2),
  y = rev(seq(0, 1, .2))))))

> data4
  a b forPrint    forXyplot
1 0 1        a c(0, 0.2....
2 1 2        b c(0, 0.5....
3 2 3        c c(0, 0.2....

ecdfplot(~ a|b, data = data4
         ,layout=c(1,3)              
         ,panel=function(x, subscripts = subscripts, ...){
            # plotData is passed to the panel function via the ellipses,
            # so extract those arguments vial match.call
            args <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
            # Print the column forPrint
            print(args$plotData$forPrint[subscripts])
            # Plot the forXyplot column using do.call, since the column is
            # a list with x and y items.
            do.call(panel.xyplot, c(args$plotData[subscripts, "forXyplot"][[1]],
              col=2))
          }
          ,plotData = data4
     )
```

You'll notice from the plot that the x-axis limits cover the range of `a` and extend beyond the range of the plotted values. Of course, one could correct this by using a custom prepanel function.

Comment: `it would be best to organize your data frame in an appropriate way before plotting`

that is my only solution for now. But the data are organized as objects with certain parameters. It would be less code if I could extract the plotting data and specific parameters from certain objects giving through the panel.function. 

`In full generality, the return value of prepanel can be a list consisting of components xlim, ylim, xat, yat, dx, and dy.`

I try to do so, but I dont get a working example.

Comment: @Klaus, ah, now I see what you're trying to do (I think). However, the default `prepanel` function is still being called. I'm about to go out, but I can take a further look at your question later.

Comment: @Klaus, after further pondering, I'm not sure exactly what your goal is. Perhaps if you could expand your question with exactly what it is you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: imagine you would use arbitrary objects in place of diagonal matrices in the snd data.frame above. In detail, every object contains numeric vectors x and y, which should passed to the panel.xyplot function and a character vector for a label. It would be nice, if I dont have to rebuild the data for ecdfplot function. So if I could extract the x,y vectors from my objects inside the panel function I have also access tothe specific label of these data.

Comment: @Klaus, please see the update. If that doesn't give you an idea of what to do, please consider editing your original post to provide more details.

Comment: Thx, I was also thinking about that before. A question to your code: is there a reason to use match.call instead of `args<-list(...)` or `panel=function(x, plotData, subscripts = subscripts, ...)`?

Comment: @Klaus, I've seen `match.call` used this way before, but there's probably not much difference using `list(...)` in this case. As to having `plotData` as a formal argument to the panel function, that might get unwieldy if you pass many objects this way. At the moment, though, I can't think of any reason to completely reject any of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

convert `x` to a numeric correct the problem

```
    x <- x[[1]]
    panel.xyplot(as.numeric(x),.5,col=2)
```

Comment: sry I cant see what you mean. The error msg comes from the snd plot, how I mentioned. I tried your hint for it, but there are no differences.

Comment: currently I try to prevent the error msg by defining a own prepanel function but it seems to it will not help.